# Flink - using rebalance affect event time processing

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Using rebalance before assign watermark function affects event time processing

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
            StreamExecutionEnvironment see = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironmentWithWebUI(config);

            see.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);


            DataStream<String> stream = see
                    .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>("testTopic3", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties));


            stream.rebalance()
            .map(event->{
                JSONObject jsonEvent = new JSONObject(event);
                Event formedEvent = new Event();
                formedEvent.setTimestamp(Long.parseLong(jsonEvent.getString("time")));
                System.out.println("formed event : "+formedEvent.getTimestamp());
                return formedEvent;
            })
            .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new TimestampExtractor())
            .keyBy(event->{
                return "1";
            }).window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5), Time.seconds(5)))
            .trigger(new TriggerFunc())
            .process(new ProcessWindowFunction());

            see.execute();
```

The event time triggers don't trigger when I use rebalance. Once it is removed, it seems to work fine. Is there a reason why this does not work?

The following seems to work:

```
Configuration config = new Configuration();
            StreamExecutionEnvironment see = StreamExecutionEnvironment.createLocalEnvironmentWithWebUI(config);

            see.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.EventTime);


            DataStream<String> stream = see
                    .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer<>("testTopic3", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties));


            stream
            .map(event->{
                JSONObject jsonEvent = new JSONObject(event);
                Event formedEvent = new Event();
                formedEvent.setTimestamp(Long.parseLong(jsonEvent.getString("time")));
                System.out.println("formed event : "+formedEvent.getTimestamp());
                return formedEvent;
            })
            .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new TimestampExtractor())
.rebalance()
            .keyBy(event->{
                return "1";
            }).window(SlidingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5), Time.seconds(5)))
            .trigger(new TriggerFunc())
            .process(new ProcessWindowFunction());

            see.execute();
```

Adding my Trigger Function. My trigger function is not doing much. Just printing a statement

```
public class TriggerFunc  extends Trigger<Event, TimeWindow>{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    public TriggerResult onProcessingTime(long time, TimeWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("On processing time purging : " + window.getStart());
        return TriggerResult.FIRE;
    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onEventTime(long time, TimeWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("On eventTime time");
        return TriggerResult.FIRE_AND_PURGE;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear(TimeWindow window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {

    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onElement(ThresholdEvent element, long timestamp, TimeWindow window, TriggerContext ctx)
            throws Exception {
        System.out.println("On element");
        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share the implementation of the trigger function. 

I have tried to reproduce the example with the flow you have provided. It works for me. My guess is that there is an issue in the trigger function.

Comment: @chuckskull, AM not doing much in the trigger function. I've update the question with the trigger function.

Comment: can you check by changing the parallelism to 1 in the environment?

Comment: @chuckskull, setting the parallelism to 1 worked. But what do I do what I want an increased parallelism?

Comment: Do you *really* want to use this trigger function? It seems faulty. Theoretically, it shouldn't work correctly. I think removing this trigger function will work perfectly fine. Let flink use the default trigger.

Comment: @chuckskull, when you say theoretically it shouldn't work, any reason why?

Comment: Window is being fired/invoked in `onProcessingTime` and `onEventTime`. However, these methods are called if event-time or processing-time timer is registered in the trigger. No timer is being registered in `onElement`.

Comment: @chuckskull, but if that is the case, it should have not worked even with a rebalance right?